# Symfony FOSUserBundle Translations aren't showing

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I enabled the Translator service in my config.yml, cleared cache and installed assets using the command line interface.

My login page still says "security.login.submit". I am using a custom template, which is located in: `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig` and contains (copied from the FOS provided template):

```
{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}
```

My config.yml:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this your own copy of the `login.html.twig`?

If so have you included the trans_default_domain..

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
```

If not the translator will be looking for translations in the default "messages" file.

Comment: *headdesk* Thanks, that was it :) I'll accept in a few minutes.

Comment: It is also true that `{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}` must be inside `{% block fos_user_content %}`, as determined by what happens when it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I think it just applies to all translations in the template that it is set in (so any blocks but not require's) but I may be wrong. Even then I think the domain can be changed by using `{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'CUSTOM_DOMAIN | messages | validation | etc }}`.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the cache was not cleared. To clear your cache:

```
rm -rf ./var/cache/*
```